# Windows 10 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind on all ports

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to fire an instance of Zookeeper from my windows command line. No matter what port I try I get the error

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:90)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:120)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:89)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:55)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:119)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
```

I have tried all types of crazy ports which are open, e.g 2188, 2180 etc.

None of these ports show up on netstat commands. Is this a JDK issue specific to Windows 10?

thanks

Comment: You have something else running already. Another zookeeper?

Answer (score -1):

Disable your antivirus and make sure you are not listening on those ports already.